# One button for two function in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button

I have this one button call btnSave

```
  <button id="btnSave" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" onserverclick="btnSave_ServerClick">Save</button>
```

Behind code rite now for save function:

```
  Protected Sub btnSave_ServerClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
-- more coding here --
    End Sub
```

I want to use this button for Save or Update the form.

How to make it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know if the thing the button press is intending to save is an existing thing or not. And this depends on your implementation, we can't tell you how you, specifically, would know this; an idea is to use a unique identifier, as provided by the database, for instance.

If you save an item, and it automatically (or however) gets a unique identifier attributed to it, then output that with the page on load (or, have your "edit" page use a query string which specifies the id of the thing that is to be edited, if it doesn't exist or the thing it relates to doesn't exist, then the item is new), and on submit check to see if the thing with that id exists - if so, update, otherwise assume it's a new thing and create.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere relevant like load you could do this (pseudo code)

```
if(requires save)
{
    btnSave.Click += new EventHandler(ClickSave);
}
else
{
    btnSave.Click += new EventHandler(ClickUpdate);
}
```

then have these

```
public void ClickUpdate()
{
   //do stuff
}

public void ClickSave()
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: This may well simply be redundant and lead to code duplication if they OP is using any kind of modern data layer - most code of these methods would likely be nigh identical save for the line of code that saves or updates. This answer also really doesn't answer the fundamental question of discerning "requires save", it seems.

Comment: I did say pseudo code, to get the idea across. the methods may well reference a 3rd method which completes the common functionality. I left that up to the OP

Comment: Which essentially leaves the whole question to the OP still.

Comment: It gives him a way to do what he needs. I can't write his app for him though.

Comment: _'It gives him a way to do what he needs'_. Hardly. I'm saying it precisely doesn't, and in your own words.

Comment: well, that's great but I disagree with you. _"I want to use this button for Save or Update the form. How to make it happen?"_ My code sample shows how to attach 2 different event handlers depending on your need.